# Why shouldn't I build a Last Whisper after Infinity Edge, Blood Thirster, and Black Cleaver?

Tags: league-of-legends

In every League of Legends game that I've ever seen, the AD carry usually rushes Infinity Edge and then builds Bloodthirster and Black Cleaver afterwards. Instead of building a Last Whisper like I expect, they usually build something else after those items.

Are there any cons to building a Last Whisper after the Infinity Edge, Bloodthirster and Black Cleaver?

Answer (score 2):

You generally dont build a last whisper after the black cleaver because flat Armor Pen makes the % armor pen less effective.

Say they have 100 armor. Black cleaver removes 45 armor, then your masteries remove another 6, then your 10% armor pen from masteries plays in, leaving the person with 45 armor. 40% of 45 armor is only a 10% damage increase, if that. And thats coming into play if the person actually bought enough armor to put them at 100.

Generally another AD item will give you more speed or sustain while providing more than a 10% damage increase.

Comment: It doesn't make it *less* effective, just less *gold* effective.

Answer (score 0):

when i play ad carry i go IE first, into a phantom dancer usually, then last whisper. why? because damage is THE single most important thing on an ad carry first and foremost. then once you have the damage you need to do it quickly, AKA the phantom dancers attack speed + the critical strike bonus. usually if you are fed they will buy armor and try to counter you with randuins or something similar. in which last whisper is then required. it is very important believe me, its just not as important as the damage variant on your champion.

Answer (score 0):

Because Last Whisper is to counter 200+ armor. By the time you get your IE+BT/PD, they're only starting to build up that 200+ armor.